# An SMTP to address is required to send a message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I am trying to send a reset password email with Devise.

Error:

```
: An SMTP To address is required to send a message. Set the message smtp_envelope_to, to, cc, or bcc address.
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/check_delivery_params.rb:9:in `check_delivery_params'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/network/delivery_methods/smtp.rb:98:in `deliver!'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:2129:in `do_delivery'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:234:in `deliver'
from (irb):27
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
```

I tried constructing a mail object manually:

```
mail = Mail.new do
  from    'name@mydomain.com'
  to      'name@mydomain.com'
  subject 'This is a test email'
  body    File.read('body.txt')
end
```

and running `mail.smtp_envelope_to` returns `[]`. When I ran `mail.To = 'name@mydomain.com',`mail.smtp_envelope_to`returns`["name@mydomain.com"].

Why am I getting this error?

EDIT: SMTP_SETTINGS

```
if Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?
  SMTP_SETTINGS = {
    address: ENV['SMTP_ADDRESS'], # example: 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
    authentication: :plain,
    domain: ENV['BASE_URL'], # example: 'this-app.com'
    password: ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    port: '587',
    user_name: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']
  }
end
```

EDIT: the missing quote was a bad re-type. See the SMTP_SETTINGS for my Rails code. The first block of code is me trying to reproduce the mail error from the console.

Comment: I'd imagine because you're not put a closing `'` on the from address

Comment: if Rails.env.staging? || Rails.env.production?
  SMTP_SETTINGS = {
    address: ENV['SMTP_ADDRESS'], # example: 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
    authentication: :plain,
    domain: ENV['BASE_URL'], # example: 'this-app.com'
    password: ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    port: '587',
    user_name: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']
  }
end

Comment: I'll ask the stupid question: Does the user record in question **have** an email? And are you using Devise's default mailer or a custom one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out a Gem from Suspenders I thought I removed, recepient-interceptor, was left in.

Removing that fixed the issue.

Comment: [Configuring it](https://github.com/croaky/recipient_interceptor#rails-example) would also fix the issue, if staging isn't used by end users.

Comment: Thanks @colinm. End users started using it.